# Execute query in portions and return values jQuery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was attemping to Insert data into the database in portions and return the results in portions.
Attempted this by putting the request in a while loop and appending the results. Didn't know if there was a better way but i thought i'd try this.

**HTML**

```
<button class="id = "start"><span>Start</span> </button>
<tbody id = "results">
    <!-- Table Data -->
</tbody>
```

**JS**

Couldn't get this to work not sure why i'm not familiar with javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#start").click(function(){    

   var start = 0;
   var stop = 10;
   var limit = start + ',' + stop;
   while(results == 10){

   $.ajax({
      url: "embed.php",
      type: "get",
      datatype : "json", 
      data:{ limit: limit } ,
      success : function(data) 
   {
      $("#results").prepend(data);
      start = start + 10;
   }, error : function(data)
   {
      console.log('error');
   }
   });
   }
   });
});
```

Decleared var results = 10; in a script tag in header.

**PHP**

Calls the function that performs the query and returns an array of success messages.

```
<?php 
$limit = filter_var($_REQUEST["limit"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$results = $insertData->insertMovies($limit);
$i = 1;
foreach($result as $item){?>
    <tr ><td><?php echo $item; $i++;?></td></tr >
<?php }?>
<script>results = <?php echo $i;?>;</script>
```

Comment: `while(results = 10)` should be `while(results == 10)`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I just notice a error in the console "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" at the line "success : function(data)" tried different thing to solve but no luck.

Comment: fixed the problem but the browser freezes when i run the script.

Comment: Yikes... Let's see if it's generating huge data?

Comment: fixed the problem by using a function with a setTimeout instead of a while loop. It was my mistake for thinking it would append the data as the while loop is running.